# Defing shortcut for live surrounding template

Tags: templates, phpstorm

How abbreviation of surrounding live template can be used? (For example `t`,...)
In non-surrounding template typing abbreviation and pressing tab will insert template, but I surrounding template we first select a portion of code and we not type abbreviation.

How can I define a shortcut for a specific surrounding template, for example
how can I define a template so when I select a portion of code and **then press `g` key**, selected code be surrounded by `<?=_('` and `')?>`?

Answer (score 5):

> How abbreviation of surrounding live template can be useful?

Everyone decides for himself how this or another thing is useful, therefore even if it is useful for me it does not necessary mean that it will be useful for you.

But generally speaking -- it can be **very** useful for me by speeding up my work -- instead of typing some text (that requires lot of cursor movement or typing different characters) I can enter it with just few keystrokes.

> How can I define a template

1. http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/webhelp/creating-and-editing-live-templates.html

2. **Settings | Live Templates**

3. Create new entry:

- Abbreviation: whatever you think is good
- Description: Whatever you want
- Template Text: `<?=_('$SELECTION$')?>`
- Context: HTML, I guess (select other applicable contexts if necessary).

Now, when it is saved -- go to file where you want to use it, select the text and then invoke **Code | Surround with Live Template...** and choose desired template from dropdown list

---

To answer revised question (you at least could bother to leave a comment about it):

**Abbreviation means virtually nothing for SURROUND templates**, because they are invoked COMPLETELY differently to normal live templates. If you want this to be completed with one `g` key -- try recording macro - may work or may not (I just do not see much point -- it will save 1 key-combo only).

Comment: On a Mac, it's Preferences | Live Templates
In my case, I added JavaScript to a pre-existing surrounding brackets "applicable" list. Then, in the file, use Cmd-Opt-J to invoke, after selecting the text to surround. A drop-down list comes up with all the applicable templates (in my case, just one, so I pressed Enter to select it).